# how to modify the color or material of link in gazebo version 1.2?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

when I follow the tutorial to modify the color or material like " " or "color rgb ", gazebo will appear errors, how can I modify the color or materials?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/242/how--to-modify-the-color-or-material-of-link-in-gazebo-version-1.2?/) by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 75 on 2012-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey, here is an example that works in Gazebo 1.2.5:

```
    <material>
      <script>
        <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
        <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
      </script>
    </material>
```

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/131/piyushk/) on 2013-01-09**:
Are you using this code in a URDF file or a SDF file?

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-01-09**:
it is an SDF file

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-01-09**:
Check out the SDF documentation: http://gazebosim.org/sdf

**Comment by [J_Schaefer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2326/j_schaefer/) on 2015-12-03**:
This doesn't work for me.
I try to spawn e.g. a simple box from an urdf.xacro-file.
And it always is white in Gazebo (2.2.3).
Is there another way, that allows me to set the color?